# Передача PHP переменной для её обработки через crontab

Tags: php, mysql, cron

Нужно передать переменную из одного скрипта в другой. Второй скрипт запускается через crontab. Передача через сессию не работает. Также не удается вывести данные из БД. При этом, если запустить второй скрипт в браузере, то переменная передается как через сессию, так и через БД.

Comment: А почему не удается передать значение через базу данных - она же общая для обоих скриптов? Можно больше подробностей? Как передаете значение?

Comment: так запускайте второй скрипт с помощью http-клиента (браузера) — wget, curl и т.п.

Comment: С базой данных разобрался. Надо было указывать полный путь к файлу подключения. Но лучше, конечно через сессию. Можете подсказать как правильно использовать wget и с какими ключами?

Comment: Пробывал сделать через curl, но опять же, через сессию не хочет, только если явно указанна переменная. В логах пишет undefined index name. Я так понимаю, имеtтся ввиду $_SESSION['name'].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Второй скрипт запускается

вероятно, скрипты эти являются частью веб-сайта. значит, «запускать» их с помощью интерпретатора *php*, скорее всего, бессмысленно: они при этом не получат необходимую для работы информацию — имя сайта, путь к *docroot*-у и т.д. и т.п.

надо делать *http-запрос* к **веб-серверу**, чтобы он сформировал всё необходимое окружение и **сам** запустил интерпретацию ваших скриптов.

сделать *http-запрос* можно с помощью *http-клиента*. например, веб-браузер — это тоже *http-клиент*, только очень «навороченный». для выполнения автоматизированных регулярных *http-запросов* веб-браузер, конечно, не предназначен. такие задачи лучше выполнять более простыми *http-клиентами*. например, *wget*, *curl* и т.п.:

```
$ wget url
$ curl url
```

> Передача через сессию не работает

для работы встроенного в *php* механизма сессий необходимо сохранение и повторное использование *cookie*.

в случае, например, *wget* для этого служат (как минимум) три опции:

- `--load-cookies /путь/к/файлу` — загружает *cookie* **до** выполнения *http-запроса* из указанного файла.
- `--save-cookies /путь/к/файлу` — сохраняет переданные веб-сервером *cookie* перед завершением работы в указанный файл.
- `--keep-session-cookies` — указание программе *wget* (при использовании опции *--save-cookies*) сохранять **и** т.н. «сессионные» *cookie*, которые, «по правила», *http-клиент* должен хранить только в течение сессии, и удалять после её завершения (или завершения своей работы).

так как вас вряд ли интересует содержимое веб-страничек, которые возвращают вам те самые скрипты, вам надо отправить это содержимое в `/dev/null` с помощью опции `-O`. если этого не сделать, *wget* попытается сохранить это содержимое в файл.

резюмируя, приведу пример вызова:

```
$ wget --load-cookies /tmp/cookiefile --save-cookies /tmp/cookiefile \
  --keep-session-cookies -O /dev/null http://ваш.сервер/ваш.скрипт
```

в этом примере *cookie* будут храниться между вызовами команды в файле `/tmp/cookiefile`.